# Перевод текста

Tags: лингвистика

Как правильно перевести на современный русский язык текст из молитвы ", еже на пользу во утешение и спасение кое муж доустрояющи

Answer (score 1):

"Чудотворному Твоему образу припадающе, молимся Тебе, всещедрей Матери человеколюбиваго Владыки: удиви на нас пребогатыя милости Твоя и прошения наша, приносимая Тебе, Скоропослушнице, ускори исполнити все, **еже на пользу во утешение  и спасение коемуждо устрояющи**."

Так должно быть понятнее. Коемуждо = каждому.

Остальное без комментариев.